# How to measure if Node.js application is leaking memory in an automated test suite?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

There is a lot of tooling that allows to inspect processes to determine whether they are leaking memory. However, I've not found a lot of documentation/examples over how one would create an automated test to ensure that memory is not leaking.

In particular, I am the author of a Postgres library `slonik` and I want to ensure that a simple query is not leaking memory.

The basic idea is that I want to run a query X times and check if memory usage for JavaScript objects, string, closures, etc. remains constant.

I tried to devise a simple test to validate if that is possible to do using `process.memoryUsage()`:

```js
const measureMemory = (routine) => {
  const before = process.memoryUsage();

  routine();

  const after = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log('heap used: ' + ((after.heapUsed - before.heapUsed) / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB');
};

measureMemory(() => {});

measureMemory(() => {
  let largeArray = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < 10000000; index++) {
    largeArray.push({ number: index });
  }

  largeArray = null;
});

measureMemory(() => {});
```

I was expecting the output of this test to be:

```markdown
heap used: 0.00 MB
heap used: 0.00 MB
heap used: 0.00 MB
```

However, it is actually:

```markdown
heap used: 0.00 MB
heap used: 577.52 MB
heap used: 0.00 MB
```

It appears I am not accounting for something, most likely garbage collection.

What would be the correct way to devise such an experiment?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is *the* solution (and it is not ideal since I cannot use it without `--expose-gc` option), but I found that explicitly invoking `gc()` before and after the benchmark produces the expected results, i.e.

```js
const measureMemory = async (routine) => {
  global.gc();

  const before = process.memoryUsage();

  await routine();

  global.gc();

  const after = process.memoryUsage();

  console.log('heap used: ' + ((after.heapUsed - before.heapUsed) / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB');
};

measureMemory(() => {});

measureMemory(() => {
  let largeArray = [];

  for (let index = 0; index < 10000000; index++) {
    largeArray.push({ number: index });
  }
});

measureMemory(() => {});
```

```bash
$ node --expose-gc .test.ts
heap used: -0.07 MB
heap used: 0.30 MB
heap used: 0.29 MB
```